# gRPC connection pooling on server side

Tags: azure, kubernetes, .net-core, grpc, azure-aks

I have a cluster of microservices to be hosted on Azure Kubernetes Service.
These microservices are .NET Core based and will

- talk to on-premises services via gRPC
- stream data using SignalR Core to client apps(Websockets)

[image]

The problem I can't find a good solution for is "How to persist gRPC" connections as pods are created and destroyed.

This seems like a very trivial problem for hosting microservices on a hybrid network. I would love to hear how others have addressed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Persistance of grpc would be difficult in such environment as pods are not persistant at all. I would suggest two approach to handle this scenario

1. Use/build a proxy between EKS and On Premises Service which can keep persistant connection open with on-premises service but connection to proxy can be added/removed as the pods are created/destroyed. This proxy can act as connection pool and provide higher throughput to on-premises service invocation.
2. Don't worry about the persistance of connection with on-premises services (treat this like a rdbms connection which can be created or destroyed on demand but has some cost in order to create new). This approach would work in case the pods are created or destroyed not too frequently.

I would suggest second approach in case the pods are not created/destroyed too frequently (few every hour) as it has less moving parts. But if pods are scaled up too frequently, approach one should be used.